# Am I understanding the China Card right in Twilight Struggle?

Tags: twilight-struggle

I want to make sure I understand this right.

Most cards, I can either choose the Event, or use the OPS Points in the top-left corner.  If I choose the Event, **then the OPS points in the corner is irrelevant** to that specific card play (unless the Event tells me otherwise).

However, for the China Card, if I choose the Event, I actually **do use** the 4 OPS points for that card.

Is that correct?  I am under the impression that OPS Points are only relevant if I ignore the Event.  But the China Card was throwing me off.

On a side note, I understand the concept that if I am holding a card that helps my enemy, and I choose to use the OPS points, the Event triggers anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct. The China Card is only used for operation points. What's unique about the China Card is the operations value differs depending on where you decide to spend the points. If you spend all of the points inside Asia (and Southeast Asia) you can use 5 OP instead of the 4 printed on the card. If you use the card anywhere else, or in combination with Asia, you can spend 4.

Additional notes from [the Deluxe Edition rulebook:](http://www.gmtgames.com/living_rules/TS_Rules_Deluxe.pdf)

> 9.1 China’s role in the Cold War 
>   is abstracted through ‘The China 
>   Card’. Either player may play 
>   ‘The China Card’ as if it were part 
>   of his regular hand. ‘The China 
>   Card’ does not count towards the 
>   hand limit.

and

> 9.2 Every play of ‘The China 
>   Card’ counts as one of the Actions 
>   (6 or 7) that a player is permitted 
>   during a turn. As a result, players 
>   may have more cards left in their 
>   hand than usual, if ‘The China 
>   Card’ is played.

Comment: Got it.  And I remembered, that the China Card can NOT be used as a Headline Phase card.  Thanks for the reply.